# Using Ruby & Github API to filter commits by date

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I am using the [ruby gem 'octokit'](https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit) which implements the Github API v3.  Mostly works great but I cannot seem to filter by date.  I believe I have the syntax and time format correct, but it appears my option is ignored and the API returns the past 35 entries regardless of the since or until dates.

Here's a minimal reproducible example (after installing the octokit gem).

```
require 'octokit'
require 'time'

@day = "2012-09-27"
@until = DateTime.parse(@date).iso8601
@since = (DateTime.parse(@day) - 60*60*48).iso8601
a = Octokit.commits({:username => "cboettig", :repo => "labnotebook", :since => @since, :until => @until})
```

see the date of the output of last entry

```
a.last.commit.author.date
```

explicit day doesn't work either

```
b = Octokit.commits({:username => "cboettig", :repo => "labnotebook", :since => "2012-09-27T00:00:00+00:00"})

b.last.commit.author.date
```

The date I get in both examples is from August, outside the specified range given.  What did I miss?

**Background**: I'm trying to write a little Jekyll plugin that uses the API to return commits made to a specified repo on the day of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[joeyw gives a great answer to this question here](https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit/issues/141#issuecomment-9002057).

The second argument should be the sha or branch, and options should be the third argument, e.g.

```
Octokit.commits("cboettig/labnotebook", "master", :since => "2012-09-28T00:00:00+00:00").length
```

or

```
Octokit.commits("cboettig/labnotebook", nil, :since => "2012-09-28T00:00:00+00:00").length
```

works just fine.  [Here's my corresponding jekyll plugin](https://github.com/cboettig/jekyll-labnotebook-plugins/blob/master/octokit.rb)